# How can I get a user's password from an HTML form into a server side SecureString without having a string in memory

Tags: javascript, c#, ssl, encryption

I have a theoretical situation where I'd want to use a SecureString to store a password provided by a web forms user, for later use by the server to accomplish a task where it would need to provide the plaintext password to a different web service.

I understand it will almost definitely be in plaintext when it's being used - unless I can figure out a way to get it at least protected via SSL to the web service, but I'd prefer to keep it obscured/encrypted from the moment the user submits it, until it is provided to the end point web service.

So, I believe the following is correct:

- The connection to acquire the password is via SSL
- Standard web forms would provide the data to my server side code via strings
- SecureString can(must?) be initialized with a series of bytes
- SecureString would be stored as encrypted text (encrypted/decrypted by the same account on the same computer)

Unless I miss my guess, the password would be in plaintext in server memory between the receipt of the form data and the processing code. If so, and it's not too terribly complicated, I'd like to avoid that. I thought of encrypting the password on the browser side before submitting to the server, using a public key generated by the server and provided in the page for JavaScript to use. This would then be decrypted using the private key and passed to the SecureString byte by byte.

Every single question and article I've found asking about encryption in JavaScript is put in the context of using it as a replacement for SSL, or talking about generating keys in the browser, in the hopes of protecting against man-in-the-middle attacks. I would have SSL, would generate the key server side, and would of course have to trust the user's browser (is there any other way?). Nothing's perfect, obviously, and a string existing in memory for a moment isn't too bad, but I'd prefer to limit the surface area as much as possible. I've found a few JavaScript libraries that claim to do RSA, but precious little commentary on the quality or usability of any of them.

What is the best way to do this? I think it may be overkill, but is it complete overkill - or just a little? Is there an easier way?

I'd probably be satisfied if the password was simply cached and provided for processing as a byte array rather than a string - so that would be an acceptable alternative. Should I simply split the password into multiple fields, then "glue" them back together via the SecureString?

Comment: Why? It's almost impossible for an attacker to get access to the memory of an application. If the user has access to the physical server, it's over anyway.

Comment: @NickBailey - that's what many OpenSSL users thought, too... but I hear you - you vote complete overkill, I take it?

Comment: The solution isn't to encrypt data in memory, it's to not use directly addressed memory in your authentication schemes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more important bits to get right are up to date versions of ssl, tls or whatever you use to secure the channel, and how the authenication and password storage is handled. There are likely to be many more profitable entry points for a hacker than server memory that you want to work out before worrying about this.

Https should already be encrypting communication between your browser and the server at a much lower level than you normally have access to. I also wouldn't trust a javascript based solution because it is so easy to see source and manipulate on the client. It might be possible, but I would be skeptical.

As for the server side I would read up on one-way hashing techiniques if you are rolling your own seurity.

Comment: The server would need a plaintext password to provide to a third party at a later time - I don't believe any form of Hashing would be acceptable. Since this would then most likely need to be put into plaintext in memory at that point, I'm probably simply not going to worry about it being there for a moment as it gets set - there are bigger, easier pain points to to exploit